# How to get wifi direct( wifi p2p) on my HP DM1 laptop?

Tags: wireless, hp, ralink, wpa2, wifi-direct

I am an Ubuntu newbie. I have a HP DM1 laptop with Ralink RT5390 wifi card. It has the ability to connect on wifi direct with my Nexus 7 in Windows while using latest drivers located at Mediatek site. But I am unable to use wifi direct in Ubuntu. I found `wpa2_supplicant` supports this and installed the same, but still wifi direct is not functioning.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

You have to compile and install wpa_supplicant (see http://www.ab9il.net/linuxwireless/wpa_supplicant.html) and before compiling edit the ".config" file as in http://wireless.kernel.org/en/developers/p2p/howto .

Now use wpa_cli commands (see http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/OMAP_Wireless_Connectivity_NLCP_WiFi_Direct_Configuration_Scripts  and http://svn.dd-wrt.com/browser/src/router/hostapd-wps/wpa_supplicant/README-P2P?rev=16495)

Hope it helps

**EDIT:**
If you get errors in Ubuntu 14.04 during the compile like: `fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.` and `fatal error: netlink/genl/genl.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated` you may need to  install libnl1, libssl-dev and libnl-dev. Use the following command to install them

`sudo apt-get install libnl1 libssl-dev libnl-dev`

Comment: wpa_supplicant v1.1 and above(v2.0) supports wifi direct

Comment: When will the Ubuntu NetworkManager applet support it?

Comment: Wifi-Direct on NetworkManager - Gnome.org WIKI: https://wiki.gnome.org/NetworkManager/WifiDirect

Comment: @Meetai.com: The GitHub of that project says "*This is an experimental implementation of Wi-Fi Display (aka Miracast).*"