# What's the statue of Wifi Direct in Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, p2p

Android now supports Wifi-Direct by default. Windows 8 has also this capability. What's the statue of Wi-Di in Ubuntu ? Especially with Ubuntu Touch coming I'd be very useful.

I need this technology for developing a Ubuntu software and I haven’t seen anything concerning Ubuntu and Wifi direct. I fear I'll have to switch to Android or Windows 8.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Wifi Drivers supporting Wifi Direct are available for ubuntu as well.For details see the question [How to get wifi direct( wifi p2p) on my HP DM1 laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258027/how-to-get-wifi-direct-wifi-p2p-on-my-hp-dm1-laptop)