# How to setup Wifi Direct

Tags: 13.04, p2p, wifi-direct

I am trying to configure Wifi Direct to connect to a 4.1 Android Phone. What are the correct steps to setup and configure wifi Direct to connect to a Phone that supports the same feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the open source implementation of wifi direct from the wpa_supplicant version 2.0.You can download it from http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/ .Look at the the answer  [How to get wifi direct( wifi p2p) on my HP DM1 laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258027/how-to-get-wifi-direct-wifi-p2p-on-my-hp-dm1-laptop/304352#304352).

I Hope that works fine.

Comment: I think the question should be marked as a duplicate of the one you mentioned rather than posting a similar answer. Thanks for pointing this out by the way. :)