# fatal error: netlink/genl/genl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: hostapd, cross-compilation

I am cross-compiling hostapd for openwrt. I am getting `fatal error: netlink/genl/genl.h: No such file or directory`. I already have libnl-3.2.24 installed. If i directly compile (not cross-compile) then hostapd is compiling properly without any error.

Comment: For which ARCH?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can search the correct package with this command:

```
apt-file search /netlink/genl/genl.h
```

In my case the output is:

> libnl-3-dev: /usr/include/libnl3/netlink/genl/genl.h

This means, I have to install the package `libnl-3-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-3-dev
```

And you need `libnl-genl-3-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-genl-3-dev
```

Then open the `config` file:

```
nano hostap/hostapd/.config
```

and uncomment the line:

```
CONFIG_LIBNL32=y
```

Start `make` again.

Comment: "If i directly compile (not cross-compile) then hostapd is compiling properly without any error." - I doubt OP doesn't have this package.

Comment: @muru Now it works, just tested.

Comment: you are cross compiling?

Comment: @muru hmm, no cross compiling. For which architecture?

Comment: @muru eg, this works: `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-`

Comment: @A.B : i want to cross compile the hostapd package. while cross-compiling for "ARM" i am getting error.

Comment: @Rafal What is your `make ` command and what have you changed in the Makefile?

Comment: @muru : what i meant is i downloaded hostapd, untar it and gave make. It worked fine. Regarding the inbuilt hostapd in OpenWrt if i enable it in make menuconfig and give make it works ... BUT i want my hostapd (i edited few files in it) to be cross compiled which i am not able to do it coz of error i mentioned above

Comment: @A.B. : I did not change anything in Makefile I made some changes in .c files. Now i want to cross compile this hostapd as a package, so i moved myhostapd to openwrt/package/ directory and wrote a makefile for it so that i can enable it in make menuconfig. Openwrt has inbuilt libnl but myhostapd is not taking libnl path. Did u understand my problem ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23418/discussion-between-a-b-and-rafal).

Comment: @Rafal As you're a reputation 11 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Comment: May I know why `libnl-3-dev` is used, but `CONFIG_LIBNL32` needs to be disabled? isn't that `CONFIG_LIBNL32` means libnl version 3?

Answer (score 1):

The header file `.../netlink/genl/genl.h` is found in the `libnl-3-dev` package

Install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-3-dev
```

Comment: "If i directly compile (not cross-compile) then hostapd is compiling properly without any error." - I doubt OP doesn't have this package.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your cross-compiler toolchain has libnl, and libnl-genl built.
Also, make sure that the your project is able to find the libraries, for example by using the correct include and lib directories when building.
I often end up specifying them by using CFLAGS="-I$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/include" and LDFLAGS="-L$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/lib"

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have the same error as you, I have installed libnl-3 correctly, but I still have this error every time I compile, I found that it seems to be a problem with the file directory structure of libnl-3. hostapd needs the netlink/genl/genl.h file, it thinks the file exists in /usr/include/netlink/genl/genl.h, but it is actually stored in /usr/include/libnl-3/netlink/genl/genl.h, so I just need to move the libnl-3/netlink folder to /usr/include. After I performed the above work, I got the correct compilation result